# In postgreSQL, how to return number of rows where two columns have the same values. (the rows have the same data. not the cells)

Tags: postgresql

```
Movie_id    | user_id     | rating
100         |   1         | Good
101         |   1         | Good
102         |   1         | Bad
100         |   2         | Good
101         |   2         | Good
102         |   2         | Good
```

I want to return the number of rows when the movie_ids match and the ratings match in the above table. (i.e. when the users have given the movie the same rating). So, this table would return, 2. Is there a simple way to do this that I’m overcomplicating?

If there’s some way to also return the total of unique movie_id’s in the same statement, that’d be cool too but, I’m fine with just doing another query for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query with `having` clause:

```
select count(*) from (
select user_id, rating from movie group by user_id,rating having count(*)>1) as x
```

[DBfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wBdpRY2Q3MLLgS7icxWVqm/0)